# How to make foreground image in div take up full width/height of screen

Tags: css, fullscreen

I need to make an image auto-fill the width and height of the viewer's screen, while keeping the correct aspect ratio. The ultimate goal is to display a jquery slideshow in the background of the page, while also making it fill the full width and height of the screen.

This jfiddle shows an approximation of what I am talking about:  http://jsfiddle.net/hockey2112/s1d2peqh/1/

Here is the CSS from that jfiddle:

```
#slideshow {
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.slide img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.contentbox {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border:5px solid #000000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}
```

and the code:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://www.iapics.org/images/3542-wallpaper-landscape-wallpapers-1920x1080.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div class="contentbox">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

I need the image to fit the height of the screen first, and then show as much of the width of the image as will fit in the screen. If you expand and contract the viewport of that jfiddle, you'll see that the image does not fill the height of the preview panel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to do this in CSS *alone*.

You can *either* have the image stretched to 100% horizontally and centered vertically **OR** you can stretch 100% vertically and center horizontally.

However, with a little but of js, you can switch between these two options pretty easily, and that should get you what you want.

Horizontal Stretch + Vertical Center:

```
.slide.horz{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.slide.horz img {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    position:absolute; /*trick for vertical center*/
    top:0;             /*trick for vertical center*/
    bottom:0;          /*trick for vertical center*/
}
```

Vertical Stretch + Horizontal Center:

```
.slide.vert{
    height:100%;
    width:300%;        /* trick for 'zoomed' horizontal center */
    margin-left:-100%; /* trick for 'zoomed' horizontal center */
}
.slide.vert img {
    height: 100%;
    width:auto;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Then some jquery will let you switch between the classes based on the aspect ratio of the window.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   setStyle();
});
function setStyle(){ 
    var winRat=($(window).width() +0.0)/($(window).height() + 0.0);
    var imgRat = 1920.0 / 1080.0;
    //do vertical stretching
    if( winRat < imgRat){
        $(".slide").removeClass("horz");
        $(".slide").addClass("vert");
    }else{
    //do horizontal stretching
    $(".slide").removeClass("vert");
        $(".slide").addClass("horz");
    }    
}
```

Have only tested this in latest chrome. I have reason to believe it may break in ie<=8.

http://jsfiddle.net/s1d2peqh/3/

Answer (score 0):

This is the purpose of the VH (viewport height) and VW (viewport width)

```
body { width:100%;height:100%; }
#slideshow { height: 100vh;position: fixed;width: 100vw;z-index: -1; }
.slide img { height: 100vh;width: 100vw; }
```

Comment: I don't believe this is the case. This makes the image stretch in one direction or the other, destroying the aspect ratio:  http://jsfiddle.net/hockey2112/s1d2peqh/7/